# Display latest SVN update date and version on site

Tags: svn

I update my website through subversion, I was wondering is there a way to display on the webpage the latest SVN update date and current version? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `svnversion` to get the latest revision.  Not sure about the date.  Maybe check one of the files in the `.svn` directory.  Or just make a script that does your update and get it to `touch` a file if the update is successful.  You could combine these: *eg*

```
svn update && svnversion > last_update
```

Now the version number is stored in the file `last_update`, and the file modification date is set correctly.